# I cannot get a list of CSV files and their headers at the same time

Tags: django, csv, django-rest-framework

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import CSVFile
from .serializers import CSVFileSerializer
import csv
...
class CSVFileListView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        files = CSVFile.objects.all()
        file_data = []
        for file in files:
            columns = self.extract_columns(file)  # Извлекаем информацию о колонках
            file_data.append({
                'id': file.id,
                'filename': file.file.name,
                'uploaded_at': file.uploaded_at,
                'columns': columns  # Добавляем информацию о колонках в список файлов
            })
        return Response(file_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def extract_columns(self, file):
        with open(file.file.path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            columns = next(csv_reader, [])  # Извлекаем первую строку, содержащую заголовки колонок
        return columns




class CSVFileDetailView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, file_id, format=None):
        try:
            file = CSVFile.objects.get(id=file_id)
            with open(file.file.path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
                dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csv_file.read(1024))
                csv_file.seek(0)
                csv_data = list(csv.reader(csv_file, dialect=dialect))

            columns = csv_data[0]

            data = csv_data[1:]

            response_data = {
                'columns': columns,
                'data': data
            }

            return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except CSVFile.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'error': 'File not found'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Error occurred while getting the list of all files using GET:
UnicodeDecodeError at /api/v1/csv/files/
**'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 14: invalid start byte**
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/csv/files/
Django Version: 4.1.5
Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError
Exception Value:
**'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 14: invalid start byte**
Exception Location: , line 322, in decode
Raised during:  csv_reader.views.CSVFileListView

I tried to read a file using
`with open(file.file.path, 'rb', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:`
and received the error message: "binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument".

And use chardet:
`Failed to detect the encoding of the file`

Comment: Sounds like `utf-8` is not the correct encoding for that file.  What file was it trying to open?  How was that file created?  And what is the correct encoding?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read a file without the right encoding.

If you have access to Windows Notepad, try this short example.

The string is:

```
this is the st¤ing
```

In Notepad, save as ANSI encoding, save as All files and make sure the file extension ends in .csv.

[image: create csv from Notepad ANSI encoded]

Then try to read the file with `utf-8` encoding.

```
with open('some-file.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = f.read()

    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#169>", line 2, in <module>
    data = f.read()
  File "C:\Python310\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 14: invalid start byte
```

It's because the encoding is `ANSI`, not `utf-8`.

With the correct encoding specified:

```
with open('some-file.csv', 'r', encoding='ansi') as f:
    data = f.read()

    
data
'this is the st¤ing'
```

Common encodings to try are:

- latin-1
- cp1252
- utf-8
- utf-8-sig
- utf-16
- utf-16-le

Those are some. Find more info about [BOM at Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).